# Trying to figure this error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to convert python's OrderedDict to a normal dictionary and then parse it to a CSV file. I am encountering challenges with 'int' object has no attribute 'keys'

```py
data_keys = list(range(-5, -11, -1))
result = {}

for element in data_keys:
    result[element] = random()

sorted_values = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(result.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))

pprint(sorted_values)

d = dict(sorted_values)
pprint(d)

with open('ordered-values.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    fieldnames = ['keys', 'values']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for data in d:
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Full error traceback

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sharhan/Documents/CV/SOLARIS-OFFGRID/11.py", line 29, in <module>
    writer.writerow(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/csv.py", line 154, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/csv.py", line 147, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: You're using a `DictWriter`, so you're supposed to pass it an entire dictionary, not just one key.

Comment: In your own words, when you write `for data in d:`, what do you expect `data` to look like each time through the loop? When you call `writer.writerow`, what do you expect it to do? What kind of data do you think you should pass to it? Now, check the documentation and verify that.

Comment: I'm looping through the dictionary and inserting row by row. Can you please come clear with some code? I first did `writer.writerows(d)` to parse the entire dictionary but still got the same error

Comment: @JohnGordon Can you please come clear with some code as an explanation? I did what you're suggesting with `writer.writerows(d)` whereby I parsed the entire dictionary but still got same error message

Comment: @samhassan Did you manage to resolve your problem? And did my solution help you?

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully example on [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)

If you want to write row with such writer, it should have format of dict

```
{"keys": <your_key>, "values": <your_value>}
```

Which conduct us to:

```
for k, v in d.items(): # without items you have only access to keys here
    writer.writerow("keys": k, "values": v)
```

Or you could use just [writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

```
writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(fieldnames)

for data in d.items():
    writer.writerow(data)
```